# Unity2d Handle Click if GameObject not Covered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to allow clicks on a GameObject if that object is not covered.

I have tried:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position,
                Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));

            if (hit2D.collider)
            {
                 executeLogic();
            }
        }
    }
```

When covering the screen with an interstitial ad executeLogic() is still being run on click. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to maintain a flag inside AdManager script. When you Ad is shown you would require it to set to true and inside your logic for update you would have to use that boolean to stop executing logic.